# How to Import Data from one theme to another theme in wordpress using Option Tree Plugin?

Tags: wordpress

How to Import Data from one theme to another theme in wordpress using Option Tree Plugin?
I am created a theme using option tree plugin but i want to import all the content into another theme. But by bad-luck i am not successful.

Comment: if you need to import theme options or complete website contents ?

Comment: I just need to import theme options data only

Answer (score 0):

Go to Option tree -> Settings -> Export

Copy the contents present under Settings and Theme options then go to the new website and then go to

Option tree -> Settings -> Import

Paste Settings content and click import settings button, it will import all option tree settings. Then paste theme options then click import theme options button. Hope this helps

Comment: Export your Settings into a fully functional theme-options.php file. can you try this method?

Comment: @Dev how to do this.